# Kinect depth image with vertical bars

Tags: c#, opencv, computer-vision, kinect

I'm have a small problem with the kinect depth image. There are some vertical bars that are equidistant across the whole image. See [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjbY7.jpg).

I guess it has something to do with the indexing but I can't figure out what.

Following is a bribe of my code which I took from the MS site :

```
void _sensor_DepthFrameReady(object sender, DepthImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
    using (DepthImageFrame depthFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame())
    {
        if (depthFrame != null)
        {

            depthFrame.CopyDepthImagePixelDataTo(depthPixels);

            int minDepth = depthFrame.MinDepth;
            int maxDepth = depthFrame.MaxDepth;

            int colorPixelIndex = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < this.depthPixels.Length; ++i)
            {
                short depth = depthPixels[i].Depth;


                byte intensity = 0;

                if (depth >= minDepth && depth <= maxDepth)
                    intensity = (byte)depth;
                else if (depth > maxDepth)
                    intensity = (byte)maxDepth;
                //byte intensity = (byte)depth;

                // B
                this.depthColorPixels[colorPixelIndex++] = intensity;

                // G
                this.depthColorPixels[colorPixelIndex++] = intensity;

                // R
                this.depthColorPixels[colorPixelIndex++] = intensity;

                // On saute la couche A
                ++colorPixelIndex;
            }

            this.depthBitmap.WritePixels(
                new Int32Rect(0, 0, this.depthBitmap.PixelWidth, this.depthBitmap.PixelHeight),
                this.depthColorPixels,
                this.depthBitmap.PixelWidth * sizeof(int),
                0);

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found an answer to this problem?

Comment: @KevinCloet if I remember it was due to a partial occlusion of the IR captor, but I can't recall precisely.